# I'll be back to edit the question soon so I can ask questions again as this is my only negative question it says I need to improve

Tags: swift

I'll be back to edit the question soon so I can ask questions again as this is my only negative question it says I need to improve

Comment: Use NSCountedSet

Comment: Can you assume the numbers are always going to be in ascending order, and/or does order matter?

Comment: The numbers are always in an ascending order. I'd like to print out each number frequency individually.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dictionary grouping initializer and map their value count:

```
let numbers = [
    "1, 2, 3, 4",
    "5, 6, 7, 8",
    "3, 4, 5, 6",
    "1, 2, 7, 8",
    "1, 2, 3, 4",
    "3, 4, 5, 6",
    "1, 2, 3, 4"]
```

---

```
let setFrequency = Dictionary(grouping: numbers) { $0 }
    .mapValues{ $0.count }
```

or using reduce(into:)

```
let setFrequency = numbers.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1, default: 0] += 1 }

print(setFrequency)  // ["3, 4, 5, 6": 2, "1, 2, 7, 8": 1, "5, 6, 7, 8": 1, "1, 2, 3, 4": 3]
```